# Ubuntu16 cannot detect second screen while windows 10 can

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

Just installed new GPU today and update Nvidia driver. The second monitor which is connected with VGA cannot be detected. After I turn back to Win10, I modified the settings for the two screens and update drivers, it works normally. Could someone tell me how to fix this issue?

- System: Ubuntu 16 64-bit
- GPU: Nvidia 1070
- driver: nvidia-367 (installed by `apt-get install nvidia-367`, previous driver is already uninstalled before installing the new one)

Here's the output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95 
   1440x900      74.98    59.89 
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02 
   1280x960      60.00 
   1152x864      75.00 
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00 
   800x600       75.00    60.32    56.25 
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94 
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

output of `nvidia-settings -q dpys`:

```
8 Display Devices on yingweizhou-Vig800S:0

    [0] yingweizhou-Vig800S:0[dpy:0] (DVI-D-0) (connected, enabled)

      Has the following names:
        DFP
        DFP-0
        DPY-EDID-11a65174-523d-8b45-29ca-662f95bc1e15
        DPY-0
        DVI-D-0

    [1] yingweizhou-Vig800S:0[dpy:1] (HDMI-0)

      Has the following names:
        DFP
        DFP-1
        DPY-1
        HDMI-0

    [2] yingweizhou-Vig800S:0[dpy:2] (DP-0)

      Has the following names:
        DFP
        DFP-2
        DPY-2
        DP-0

    [3] yingweizhou-Vig800S:0[dpy:3] (DP-1)

      Has the following names:
        DFP
        DFP-3
        DPY-3
        DP-1

    [4] yingweizhou-Vig800S:0[dpy:4] (DP-2)

      Has the following names:
        DFP
        DFP-4
        DPY-4
        DP-2

    [5] yingweizhou-Vig800S:0[dpy:5] (DP-3)

      Has the following names:
        DFP
        DFP-5
        DPY-5
        DP-3

    [6] yingweizhou-Vig800S:0[dpy:6] (DP-4)

      Has the following names:
        DFP
        DFP-6
        DPY-6
        DP-4

    [7] yingweizhou-Vig800S:0[dpy:7] (DP-5)

      Has the following names:
        DFP
        DFP-7
        DPY-7
        DP-5
```

This is what my desktop looks like now:

[image]

The second screen is connected with VGA while the working one is connected with the GPU through DVI port. The weird thing is it works in Windows 10.

-------------------------------update----------------------------------------

I uninstalled 367 driver and install 370 instead but it still seems the same.

This is how it looks in windows:
[dropbox link, since larger than 2M.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ondao8hyzwrk61/File%2017-11-2016%2C%2016%2029%2055.jpeg?dl=0)

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `xrandr` and `nvidia-settings -q dpys` (with both screens connected and switched on)? Thanks.

Comment: This is weird indeed. The second screen isn't even detected. I'd actually contact Nvidia about this in your position. They should know more about why this particular GPU and driver may not detect a secondary VGA screen in Linux even though it works in Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it would be great helpful if they can solve this. Thx

Comment: In the mean time you can try the `nvidia-370` driver package from the [graphics drivers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

Comment: @DavidFoerster, I installed nvidia-370 but it's still remain the same situation. In ubuntu's `additional drivers`, 370.28 version is activated and there's also another `Unknown: unknown: this device is not working` which I select "do not use the device".

Comment: FYI, it is not "weird" that it works with Windows. In general, graphics drivers for Linux are very buggy, and perform worse than their Windows counterparts.

Comment: I know you have a solution, but you could also test out `nvidia-375` from the PPA and see if it helps at all.

Comment: @Zacharee1 thanks for your suggestion, I'll try it later :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by connecting the second screen with HDMI cable. I think that's the easiest solution... Thanks guys for your suggestions, now I can continue my work comfortably.